# svelte read nested store

Tags: javascript, svelte

In Svelte I can read from store using `$` symbol:

```
<script>
  export let myStore;
</script>
<p>
  {$myStore}
</p>
```

How do I read from store that is a property of an object? E.g. let's say `foo.store` is a store.

I have tried `$foo.store`, `$(foo.store)` and `foo.$store`, neither working!

I am aware I can do `let foo_store = foo.store` and then `$foo_store`, but I'm looking for a simpler way.

**EDIT** looking for solution for assignments to store too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't — for the purposes of the syntactic sugar, stores are always free variables. For that reason it's common to use destructuring:

```js
const { x, y, z } = stores;
```

Comment: Thanks Rich Harris. Btw, what's the difference between a store and a variable using `$:` assignment?

Comment: `$:` reactivity applies within a component. Stores are objects that many components can interact with. You can use them in combination.